# $L^2_{\mathbb{R}}(M)$ is closed in $L^2_{\mathbb{C}}(M)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification

I wanted to show $L^2_{\mathbb{R}}(M)$ is a closed subset of $L^2_{\mathbb{C}}(M)$, but since $L^2_{\mathbb{R}}(M)$ is not a ($\mathbb{C}$-)subspace of $L^2_{\mathbb{C}}(M)$ I am not too sure if the following is correct.

I thought it'd be alright as I don't think the scalar field is affecting the topology (we are using the metric space-ness, aren't we?), but wanted to see others agree.

---

Let $( M,\Omega ,\mu )$ be a measure space let $L^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}( M)$ be the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space consisting of $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\| f\| _{L^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}} :=\left(\int _{M} f\overline{f} d\mu \right)^{1/2} < \infty .
\end{equation*}
Let $V$ be the subset of $L^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}( M)$ consisting of real-valued functions. I want to show that $V$ is a closed subset of $L^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}( M)$.

Note that $V$ is clearly not a subspace of $L^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}( M)$, since it is not closed under the complex number multiplication.

We show the closedness. To see this, first note that for $f\in L^{2}_{C}( M)$ we have

\begin{align*}
\| f\| _{L^{2}_{C}} < \infty \ \ \Leftrightarrow  & \ \ \| f\| _{L^{2}_{C}}=\left(\int _{M} Re( f)^{2} d\mu +\int _{M} Im( f)^{2} d\mu \right)^{1/2} < \infty \\
\Leftrightarrow  & \int _{M} Re( f)^{2} d\mu < \infty \ \ \text{and} \ \ \int _{M} Im( f)^{2} d\mu < \infty .
\end{align*}
Now, we have
\begin{equation*}
V=\left\{f:M\mapsto \mathbb{R} \mid \ \| f\| _{L^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}} =\int _{M} Re( f)^{2} d\mu =\int _{M} f^{2} d\mu =:\| f\| _{L^{2}} < \infty \right\} ,
\end{equation*}
with for $f\in V$ the $L^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}( M)$-norm being $\| f\| _{L^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}} =\| f\| _{L^{2}}$. Then, $V$ is just an $L^{2}( M)$-space over $\mathbb{R}$, with the $\mathbb{R}\subset{\mathbb{C}}$ multiplication being inherited from $L^2_{\mathbb{C}}(M)$.

So for $\{f_n\}\subset V$, $\|\cdot\| _{L^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}}$-norm topology convergent is the same as $\|\cdot\| _{L^{2}}$-norm topology convergent, and thus the limit must be in $V$.

Comment: Notice that $L^2$ is not a space of functions but of equivalence classes of functions for the equivalence relation that related two functions off they coincide almost everywhere, so everything you write has to take care of this.

Comment: Of course the moment I wrote $\|\cdot\|$, by which I meant the norm, I quotiened. But sorry I don't really understand where the convention that people don't really bother to be explicit about it would be a problem here. (By real valued function I meant one can take a representative such that the imaginary part is zero.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last paragraph seems not true: For simplicity, consider the ambient space ${\bf{R}}$ with the usual norm $|\cdot|$. And consider the norm $|\cdot|_{r}$ on $(0,1)$ defined by the restriction of $|\cdot|$ on $(0,1)$. Then the sequence $\{1/n\}_{n}$ satisfies $|1/n-0|\rightarrow 0$ and at the same time $|1/n-0|_{r}=|1/n-0|$, still, $0\notin (0,1)$.

To tackle this question, for $\{f_{n}\}\subseteq V$ such that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L_{{\bf{C}}}^{2}$, then there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_{k}}\}$ such that $f_{n_{k}}\rightarrow f$ a.e., say, $f_{n_{k}}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x\in{M}-N$, where $\mu(N)=0$.

Note that $\text{Im}(f_{n_{k}})=0$ and for all $x\in M-N$, we must have $\text{Im}(f_{n_{k}})(x)\rightarrow\text{Im}(f)(x)$, so $\text{Im}(f)(x)=0$. So we conclude that $\text{Im}(f)=0$ a.e.

With the a.e. identification in $L_{{\bf{C}}}^{2}$, then $f=\text{Re}(f)$, so $f\in V$.

Note that if we want to have super rigorous argument, one may assume only that $\text{Im}(f_{n_{k}})=0$ a.e. However, the proof is almost the same, just by collecting all the sets of measure zero regarding the imaginary parts of $f_{n_{k}}$ together with $N$, and finally claim that it is still the case that the imaginary part of $f$ is a.e. zero.

Comment: Ah. Nice. I tried to show $\mathrm{Im}(f)=0$ but couldn't.

Comment: The last bit is indeed the part I wasn't sure of. But regarding the counterexample, I think the example provided is the case where the ambient space is complete normed space but the subset $(0,1)$ with the same norm is not closed. But in our setting isn't $(V,\|\cdot\|_{L^2_{\mathbb{C}}})$, which is the same as $(V,\|\cdot\|_{L^2_{\mathbb{R}}})$, a complete metric space (and thus any convergent sq., which must be Cauchy, must have the limit in itself?)?

Comment: The point is that, completeness is not necessarily subspace-inherited. It is when the subspace is a closed subset of the ambient space, and this is what you need to prove.

Comment: I understand that and that is why I asked this question. What I am saying is that we want to show that $L^2_{\mathbb{C}}$-convergent $\{f_n\}\subset V$ has its limit in $V$. But for $\{f_n\}\subset V$ that's the same as $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$-norm. But that's Cauchy in $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$-norm. From this point I can follow the proof of the completeness of $L^2_{\mathbb{R}}(X)$ to show the limit is in $V$ (that one where we find the candidate and show it is the one).

Comment: In doing this we do not explicitly refer to the ambience space, but implicitly we always seeing this as $L^2_{\mathbb{C}}$-elements: it is not just explicit since  $\|\cdot\|_{L^2_{\mathbb{R}}}=\|\cdot\|_{L^2_{\mathbb{C}}}$?

Comment: Okay I got your philosophy. But I will view in this way: certainly you can MIMIC the proof of the completeness of $L_{{\bf{R}}}^{2}(X)$ to claim that the limit is in $V$, but I disagree to saying that it is the completeness of  $L_{{\bf{R}}}^{2}(X)$ which finishes the job. The crucial difference here is that, the functions $L_{{\bf{R}}}^{2}(X)$ really assume everywhere real-valued whereas the $f_{n}$ in question may have a.e. zero imaginary parts, which are certainly not functions in  $L_{{\bf{R}}}^{2}(X)$.

Comment: Great that my argument seems to make sense. Yeah I did not carefully write down but I as you say I am seeing real valued function as possibly with a.e. zero complex part (which is fine, I consider only countable of them and they will be measure zero upon collecting all of them anyway), and by completeness I meant follow the same proof (which doesn't use scalar multiplication for example).

Answer (score 1):

The function mapping an element of the complex $L^2$ to its complex conjugate is continuous, that space is Hausdorff, and the set of fixed points of that function is the real $L^2$.

Comment: I wonder if this technique is a standard one in operator algebra? Regarding the complex conjugate as involution...

Comment: So letting $W$: Hausdorff topological vector space, $\sigma:W\to \sigma(W)$ continuous conjugation, if we consider $\{w\in W\mid \sigma(w)-w=0\}$, that's closed and in particular the statement in the question is true?

Comment: Well, is it true?

Comment: Ah that was my question confirming your argument posed as, "so your argument is, in general for $W$ (what I typed) holds, and thus in particular for $L^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ it is true. Is this your argument?"

Comment: If $X$ is a Hausdorff topological space and $f:X\to X$ is continuous, the set $\{x\in X:f(x)=x\}$ is closed in $X$.